# Looking for a story about an alien graveyard on the moon's far side

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in a thin old book, possibly fifty pages or fewer. I recall some black-and-white illustrations in the book, but I can't recall what they were. I also recall a brilliant and monochromatic cover (green) with a lonely planet, which could have been the Moon (I don't think it was Mars). I read the book in the mid 1970s, but based on its state, it could have been released in the 1950s or 1960s.

The plot revolved around a US satellite that landed on the far side of the moon and began sending photographs back to Earth. The photographs depicted a crater filled with metallic things. The photographs were originally examined by a scientist, who decided that they were of alien origin. A second scientist suspected that the objects were Russian, but given the quantity of debris, the first scientist developed a theory based on alien spaceships being hit by the asteroid belt and ending on the Moon.

Near the end of the story, a masked being (probably a helmeted being) appeared approaching the satellite in the last photo, which I say last because the satellite stopped transmitting photographs after that. At the end of the story, the first scientist proposed sending a manned mission to the far side of the moon, however, a general and other military personnel arrived at the room and announced that they would take over immediately.